# Invalid Base Class T error

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to do something like this, But, I am getting an error, 
"Invalid Base class T". 
As far as our understanding goes, Base class will get instantiated with Type name T in compile time and I will be getting the defination of T in compile time. I tried replacing "Typename" with "Class",still I get the same error. Any ideas ?

```
template <typename T>  
class Base  
{ 
  private:  
  class A : public T{};

};


// It works when I do the following in main ...  

class A{}  
Base* B = new Base<A> B;  

// It throws error, when I pass in int,double,float,   
//makes sense,because these are basic data types ...  

Base* B = new Base<int> B;  


// Neil's Snippet with the error reproduced ...  

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;  

template <typename T>  
class Base  
{  
 public :
 Base::Base(int a)  
 {  
   A a;
 }
 private:  
 class A : public T{};
};  

Base <int> b;  

int main(){  
cout << &b << endl;  
}
```

Comment: Obviously, replacing `typename` with `class` is not going to help. After all, they're equivalent.

Comment: Who is voting this up? The question is unclear, and the code is not even vaguely syntactically correct.

Comment: That is not a reason to vote the question down. Maybe Atul's first language is not English. Also, maybe Atul's is not yet quite accustomed to the usage of SO's text editor options. Please be patient. ;)

Comment: What is the actual question? You seem to have figured out that you cannot inherit from an integral or floating point type (besides all the typos in the question the comments say that you have made it compile). You ask for ideas to do what exactly? You have not stated the problem that you want to solve, add that information and people will be able to come with some idea on how to tackle it.

Comment: We are trying to create a Heap Object which will be doing memory management.

Answer (score 1):

`Typename` is not a valid C++ keyword, `typename` is. Similary `Class` is different from `class`.

Note that C++ is case sensitive.
Apart from that you are missing a semicolon in your code.

```
class A : public T{}; // missing semicolon here
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should compile:

```
template <typename T>  
//        ^ lower case
class Base  
{ 
  private:  
  class A : public T {}; // < lost ;

  A a; // do you use class A in this way ?
};
```

Note, that `T` should be complete type at the point of instantination. The following will fail:

```
class some; // incomplete type
Base<some> a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You got a few basic syntax errors in this which is causing you grief:
Typename should be typename and you need a semi colon after the internal class definition, so this compiles perfectly:

```
template <typename T>  
class Base  
{ 
  private:  
  class A :  public T{};

};
```

Answer (score 0):

This compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>  
class Base  
{ 
  private:  
  class A : public T{};

};

Base <int> b;

int main(){
    cout << &b << endl;
}
```

Edited for the benefit of Nawaz.

Comment: `Base<int>` will not get instantiated. :P

Comment: @Nawaz Sorry, please be less cryptic.

Comment: @Neil: `T` should be a class, because `T` is supposed to be base of the nested class `A`.

Comment: @Nawaz A good point - I wonder what GCC is doing in this case? The code I posted compiles and runs.

Comment: @Neil: How come that compiles? I am [totally surprised](http://www.ideone.com/nZcG8). Please explain. :-)

Comment: @Neil: Oh it will not compile if `Base` attempts to use the private nested class `A`: http://www.ideone.com/09HX1

Comment: @Nawaz: unless you perform explicit instantiation, members of a class template will be compiled only on demand. That is, if you only use `push_back` on a vector, the compiler will not compile `insert`. In this particular case, the inner type was not used, and as such the compiler is not required to diagnose errors there--a conforming compiler could also fail with that code, that is a quality of implementation detail.

Comment: @David: I had read something similar in Modern C++ book. Thanks a lot for this little yet insightful explanation.